# AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'TFBertModel'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

My env is created by pycharm, it has the followings packages: tensorflow==1.13.0rc1, CUDA = 11 andcorresponding cudn.but run https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/nlp/semantic_similarity_with_bert.py from 1 to 269 line,print(f"Strategy: {strategy}")
model.summary()
After execution, the following error is reported:

```
2021-08-29 00:16:22.311887: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
WARNING:tensorflow:Not all devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy` are visible to TensorFlow.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/.../PycharmProjects/.../Semantic Similarity with BERT.py", line 190, in <module>
    bert_model = transformers.TFBertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
AttributeError: module 'transformers' has no attribute 'TFBertModel'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow 2.6.0 works

```
pip install transformers
pip install tensorflow 
from transformers import BertModel, TFBertModel
```